# NSConnection throwing 303 error after large data POST

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, nsconnection

```
ERROR: Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)" UserInfo=0x1cd24f40 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://test.com/test/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://test.com/test/}
```

I can POST without an attachment and it wont break but as soon as I attach an image and POST it all other requests after that fail with 303 error. If I restart the App everything works again until I post another image.

To clarify the post works fine, the image is uploaded correctly and returns.

Comment: It's not the server returning that code that's Apples library code.

Comment: @RyanDetzel  ITs not even sending request to server! apple sending you  didFailWithError method!  I do have same problem!

Comment: Can you show your request code?

Comment: have you checked the service to be working with any REST client ?